# Given margin collapsing, how to evenly space child elements within a parent element?

Tags: margin, css

So [margin collapsing](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing) makes a child's margin collapse to the parent's margin if there is no border. How, then, can I accomplish this?

```
-------------
|           | <-- "Top space"
|  -------  |
|  |     |  |
|  |     |  |
|  -------  |
|           | <-- "Middle space"
|  -------  |
|  |     |  |
|  |     |  |
|  -------  |
|           | <-- "Middle space"
|  -------  |
|  |     |  |
|  |     |  |
|  -------  |
|           | <-- "Bottom space"
-------------
 ^        ^
left     right
space    space
```

I want all these "spaces" to be equal.

I want the space between each child to be `10px`, and the space between children and the parent to be `10px`. If I have a margin of `10px` for each child, and no padding for the parent, the "top space" and "bottom space" would be `0px`. If I have any padding in the parent, "middle space" would be different from top/bottom space.

How can I do this? I don't particularly want to float or clear any elements, or even add new elements to accomplish this. I just think I'm missing some clever math here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the easiest way:

- Just add a transparent `border` to the containing element.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/XB9wX/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid transparent /* "magic border" fixes it */
}
.square {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f0f
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `position: absolute`:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/XB9wX/1/)

Comment: Some websites say that transparent border color does not work in IE6. What does it even look like? I don't even have a machine with IE6 anymore.

Comment: It will be a black border in IE6. I don't consider IE6 in my answers (unless it's specifically asked for) because the browser is now so old. You can check it here: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ - with URL http://fiddle.jshell.net/XB9wX/2/show/light/

Comment: Another solution is `padding: 1px` on the container: http://jsfiddle.net/XB9wX/3/ You've got 3 different solutions now, hopefully you'll be able to use one of them :)

Comment: I want my boxes to be pixel perfect! The transparent border seems to be the most compatible with browsers. To get rid of that 1px difference, I can do `5px` padding on the parent all around, and `5px` transparent border on each child. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can give the child elements a margin of 10px, then the parent padding of 10px. Ill code it up

EDIT:

1. How about using borders? - No
2. parent - `display:table;`

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Alex</p>
    <p>James</p>
    <p>thomas</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{display:table;}
p{margin:10px;}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/nqLYT/](http://jsfiddle.net/nqLYT/1/)

Comment: Wouldn't that give him a space of 20px between the children?

Comment: Having a solid border is rather limiting. What if I had a background image in my parent element?

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html, IE7 does not support `display:table`. Oh well. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
.children{
margin: 5px;
}

.parent{
padding: 5px;
}
```

This should be 10px for all directions. Right?

Comment: No. The children's margins will collapse, and thus the space between each child will be `5px`.